# Why is there gaps between the cells?

Tags: javascript, css

I was trying to make a customizable grid (by default 16x16) but when it's created there's gaps in between cells.

CSS:

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    border: none;
    outline: 2px solid red;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
let gridSize = 0;

const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let input = prompt("Enter a grid size (100 or lower):");
    createGrid(input);
});

const container = document.querySelector("#container");

createGrid(16);

function createGrid(rows){

    rows = parseInt(rows);
    gridSize = rows * rows;
    container.innerHTML = "";

    for(let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++){
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = `grid`;
        container.appendChild(div);
    }

    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerText = `  
    .grid{
        height: ${800/rows}px;
        width: ${800/rows}px;
    }`;
    const body = document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

In summary the grid is made with Javascript by appending it to a container in html. I included it in case is relevant since there are some changes of styles and I imagine it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the gap was caused by `line-height` of `container`.

A quick fix would be setting a `line-height: 0` on `container` to eliminate the gap.

Example:

```
#container {
  /*   Add  */
  line-height: 0;

  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  border: none;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the div #container using the default display block is causing this. You can fix it using flexbox by adding:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

to your #container css

Comment: Whoops, it seems that John is right, the issue was the line-height, not the display: block. I'll leave my answer up though as flex does provide the requested outcome.